# _OBJC_CLASS_$ Errors While Unit Testing Custom Classes In iOS 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Alright, I've spent about 5 hours trying to figure this out. Absolutely none of the past Stackoverflow topics resolutions worked for me, so I'm hoping someone can give me an answer and not a wild goose-chase.

Problem: I have an x-code project that needs unit-testing of my custom classes. I'm using X-Code 3.2.5 with iOS SDK 4.2. After following several different ways, I cannot get my unit-testing working on custom classes. It works fine using Apple's examples.

The custom classes are simple sub-classed NSObjects with trivial iVars. We'll call the class "Snookie".

I've already attempted several questionable resolutions, but would like a response from someone who has had the exact same issue, with an answer that makes sense.

Replication:

1. Add MyAppTesting unit test bundle target.
2. Under get info on MyAppTesting, add MyApp as Direct Dependency.
3. Create a group called "Tests".
4. Under "Tests", add ObjectiveC Test Case Class.
5. In the new test case class .h, import Snookie.h, and create an iVar:

> ```
> #import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>
> #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
>
> #import "Snookie.h"
>
> @interface SnookieTests : SenTestCase {
>   Snookie *snookieObject;
> }
> @end
> ```

**In the new test case class .m, alloc/init snookie as follows:**

> ```
> #import "SnookieTests.h"
>
>
> @implementation SnookieTests
>
> - (void) setUp
> {
>   snookieObject = [[Snookie alloc] init];
> }
>
> - (void) tearDown
> {
>   [snookieObject release];
> }
>
> @end
> ```

The error:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Snookie", referenced from:
Objc-class-ref-to-Snookie in SnookieTests.o
Symbol(s) not found
Collect2: Id returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What think linker is trying to tell you is that it cannot find an `@implementation` for the `Snookie` class in `MyAppTesting` or any of the frameworks/libraries it links.

Adding `MyApp` as a directly dependency is not sufficient to tell Xcode to compile/link the code from `MyApp`. You need to explicitly add the `Snookie.m` file to your target for `MyAppTesting`.

Comment: During the time I posted that and your response, I took a different approach with the EXACT same issue. Look at Apple's documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html under the "Application Testing" section. I follow the steps EXACTLY, the import my header into the test, and still get the same result.

Comment: Nowhere in that example does it tell you how to link the classes you are testing to your test bundle.  You need to add Snookie.m to the test bundle.  That is exactly what the error is telling you.

Comment: After relaxing and taking a break, Kperry and JeremyP were 100 percent correct. The source of my subsequent errors were due to bad interface programming, which led to a refactor of code..... THANKS !!!!

Comment: This works but isn't the easiest way to do it. Check out: http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/

Answer (score 4):

While adding your app's .m files directly to your testing target solves the problem, it's redundant and unnecessary. Follow [the steps outlined here by Two Bit Labs](http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/) to get it working. To sum up, make sure your…

1. test target's `Bundle Loader` build setting is pointing at your app's bundle.
2. test target's `Test Host` build setting is pointing at your app's bundle.
3. *app target's* `Symbols Hidden by Default` build setting is `NO`.

Comment: This does not work for me.  AFter setting my Symbols Hidden by Default: NO, build & clean & build & clean & build, I still don't get my .m's linked.

Comment: This is the only correct way doing the job. All other things are adding redundancy to the project. This is working perfect if you follow the guidelines in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

kperryua is correct.

In XCode 5, click on your class-to-be-tested implementation file, (e.g. XYZCustomClass.m), make sure you can see the Utilities screen (which can be displayed under View > Utilities > Show Utilities, if hidden), and then check the [your tests name] Tests checkbox under Target Membership box. Voila, your unit tests "OBJC_CLASS_$ . . .", referenced from: objc-class-ref in . . ._Tests.o" error message will disappear.